# How to add another value to nested dictionary key in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary that looks like this and I want to add one more value to "model1" key

```
variants= {"model1" : {"orange":2} }
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
variants= {"model1" : {"orange":2, "black":1} }
```

What's the code for that? thanks

Comment: `variants = { ...variants, model1: { ...model1, black: 1 }}`

Comment: easier than @RobertoZvjerković, but not nullsafe: `variants.model1.black = 1`;

Comment: thanks, I just don't get the ... in @RobertoZvjerković answer

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can suggest is:

```
variants.model1 = Object.assign({}, variants.model1, {"black":1})
```

That would be better if you add a property check before it to be sure that `model1` exists in the variants. You can write a function like this:

```
addToDictionary(variants, key, value) {
    if(variants.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        variants[key] = Object.assign({}, variants[key], value);
    } else {
        variants[key] = value;
    }
}
```